# Unable to push docker images to artifactory

Tags: nginx, docker, repository, artifactory

I set up artifactory as a docker registry and am trying to push an image to it

```
docker push nginxLoadBalancer.mycompany.com/repo_name:image_name
```

This fails with the following error

```
The push refers to a repository [ nginxLoadBalancer.mycompany.com/repo_name] (len: 1)
unable to ping registry endpoint https://nginxLoadBalancer.mycompany.com/v0/
v2 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://nginxLoadBalancer.mycompany.com/v2/: Bad Request
 v1 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://nginxLoadBalancer.mycompany.com/v1/_ping: Bad Request
```

This is my nginx conf

```
upstream artifactory_lb {
                server mNginxLb.mycompany.com:8081;
                server mNginxLb.mycompany.com backup;
        }

        log_format upstreamlog '[$time_local] $remote_addr - $remote_user - $server_name  to: $upstream_addr: $request upstream_response_time $upstream_response_time msec $msec request_time $request_time';

        server {
                listen 80;
                listen 443 ssl;

                ssl_certificate  /etc/nginx/ssl/my-certs/myCert.pem;
                ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/my-certs/myserver.key;
                client_max_body_size 2048M;
                location / {
                        proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
                        proxy_pass http://artifactory_lb;
                        proxy_read_timeout 90;
                }
                access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log upstreamlog;
                location /basic_status {
                        stub_status on;
                        allow all;
                        }
        }

        # Server configuration

        server {
            listen 2222 ssl;

            server_name mNginxLb.mycompany.com;
            if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = '') {
                set $http_x_forwarded_proto  $scheme;
            }

            rewrite ^/(v1|v2)/(.*) /api/docker/my_local_repo_key/$1/$2;
            client_max_body_size 0;
            chunked_transfer_encoding on;
            location / {
            proxy_read_timeout  900;
            proxy_pass_header   Server;
            proxy_cookie_path ~*^/.* /;
            proxy_pass         http://artifactory_lb;
            proxy_set_header   X-Artifactory-Override-Base-Url $http_x_forwarded_proto://$host;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;
            proxy_set_header    Host              $http_host;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            }
        }
```

There are no errors in the nginx error log. What might be wrong?
 I verfied that the SSL verification works fine with the set up. Do I need to set up authentication before I push images?
I also verified artifactory server is listening on port 2222

Update,

I added the following to the nginx configuration

```
  location /v1 {
            proxy_pass http://myNginxLb.company.com:8080/artifactory/api/docker/docker-local/v1;
        }
```

With this it now gives a `405 - Not allowed` error when trying to push to the repository

Comment: What version of Artifactory are you using? We ran into this when we upgraded docker to 1.8 with an old version of Artifactory that didn't support the V2 registry yet.

Comment: The version of artifactory supports v2, and gives me an option to select either v1 or v2

Comment: I'm not sure the rewrite and the new location configured will play nicely together. Try removing the rewrite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by removing the location /v1 configuration and also changing proxy pass to point to the upstream servers